# How to Change the Color of Negative Binomial Regression Coefficients using ggcoef_model in R?

Tags: r

I'm currently designing a figure in R using the ggcoef_model function, but I'm having difficulties selecting the color for each variable in the figure. It seems that the colors are random, but I'd like to keep one consistent color using a hexcode value. Below is the code that I'm using for the figure, and an image of the output when I run it in R. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Code:

```
ggcoef_model(model.nbrm,   
         variable_labels = c(
           ParAvg="Par Avg",
           ChlAvg="Chl Avg",
           AirTempAvg="Air Temp Avg"),
           no_reference_row = broom.helpers::all_dichotomous(),
          show_p_values = FALSE,
          signif_stars = FALSE) + 
             labs(title= "Predicting Silvetia Compressa Cover in High Zone at Bechers Bay",
                  x = "Negative Binomial Regression Coefficients")
```

[image: Negative Binomial Regression Figure with unwanted colors]

I've tried using the color=  function as I'm quite new to R, but this kept yielding an error code.

Comment: This is a reasonably good question, but it would be even better if you offered a [mcve]. You can probably make one with (for example) the built-in `mtcars` data set and a plain linear model (`lm`) ...

Comment: You need to adde a color scale to the ggplot instance.  [This might be helpful](https://ggobi.github.io/ggally/articles/ggcoef_model.html#ggplot2-elements)